# How to compare a user input against multiple OR conditions PYTHON 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Apologies if this is a dumb question. I've done a bit of searching, and haven't been able to find the info I need though. I'm very new to python. Currently in the middle of the Learn Python 3 The Hard Way course.

I'm trying to write an IF statement that takes a user generated string, and compares it against a list, and then evaluates to True, if there is a match.

I have been able to do this successfully using:

```
if input in list:
    print("That was in the list.")
```

but what I'm trying to do now is swap this around and use a one off list that's part of the IF statement.  I'm doing a ZORK style game where there are rooms with doors in different walls etc, so in this case it didn't make sense to me to have a bunch of permanent lists with different configurations of 'n', 's', 'e', 'w' in them that I'd have to reference depending on which walls have doors. But I don't want to write out three separate elif evaluations that all do the exact same thing either (if I wrote one for each 'no go' direction in each room.) Hope that all makes sense.

I read somewhere that you could put a list into an IF statement like this {'up', 'down', 'left'} But when I try that it says that I don't have a string in my "in" evaluation:

```
choice = input("> ")

if {'up', 'down', 'left', 'right'} in choice:
    print("You wrote a direction!")
else:
    print("Oh bummer.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is use a list `[]` square brackets, instead of curly ones (those are for sets) and you need to move the choice variable ahead. ( You want to see that the `choice` is in the list, and not the other way around. )

Your code should be :

```
choice = input("> ")

if choice in ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']:
    print("You wrote a direction!")
else:
    print("Oh bummer.")
```

Comment: So, is there a way to do it without flipping the order though? I’d like the input to be a little more flexible. So for example the player could type “go left” and it would see that one of the words “left” in the list was included in the input.

Comment: no, you can't do that, as mentioned in the answer above, if you flip the order, python will try to search the list in the text ( which is not a valid operation ).
besides, it's a bad practice to allow too much free input, your program's complexity will significantly increase, if you start supporting, "go left", "turn left", "reverse your direction", etc. It would be much more sensible to provide the user options as to where they would like to go... not only it would be more intuitive, it would decrease your program complexity too.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong order

```py
if choice in {'up', 'down', 'left', 'right'}:
    print("You wrote a direction!")
else:
    print("Oh bummer.")
```

EDIT: Use sets for existence-checking is usually more efficient than lists

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check if any of  `'up'`, `'down'`, `'left'`, `'right'` string exists in your `choice` variable:

```py
choice = input("> ")

if any(x in choice for x in {'up', 'down', 'left', 'right'}):
    print("You wrote a direction!")
else:
    print("Oh bummer.")
```

The input format is usually pre-determined by the program though, so you could probably doing something like this:

```py
choice = input("> ")

# assuming the input is always in the format of "go <direction>"
direction = choice.split()[1]

if direction in {'up', 'down', 'left', 'right'}:
    print("You wrote a direction!")
else:
    print("Oh bummer.")
```

Or maybe you could use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) (but that's rather more complicated)